# android finding checkboxes in a linear layout

Tags: android, checkbox, android-linearlayout

i have several checkboxes added programmatically in a LinearLayout. is it possible to find and check all CheckBoxes in a LinearLayout?
my xml structure is as follows:

```
<LinearLayout>
<ScrollView>
<TableLayout>
<TableRow>
<CheckBox>
</TableRow>
<TableRow>
<CheckBox>
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Java Code:

```
CheckBox selectAll = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkboxSelectAll);
selectAll.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if(buttonView.isChecked()){
        //loop in linear layout
            //find each checkbox
            //setChecked(true);

    }

}
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can either hold a reference for the checkboxes or you can loop thru all elements using getChildCount() and then getChildAt and then check if the element is type of (instanceof) CheckBox and if it is just cast it to CheckBox and set it checked to true.

```
LinearLayout yourLayout= (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
int count = yourLayout.getChildCount();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    View v = rootLinearLayout.getChildAt(i);
    if (v instanceof CheckBox) {
        ((CheckBox) v).setChecked(true);
    }
}
```

I hope that helps

Comment: can you please elaborate and explain how this answers the question ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet what do you mean ?  the question is "is it possible to find and check all CheckBoxes in a LinearLayout" and my answer does what the user asks. or i'm missing something... ?

Comment: An answer with code only is generally considered as low quality. So if you take the time to explain your solution, it will hopefully become crystal clear you did answer the question

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet thank you for the clarification. I hope my edited version is better,

Answer (score 1):

If `CheckBoxes` are added programmatically, you can hold references to them in member variable of your `Activity` class.

Comment: yes i do have their ids and i can do a loop for each of them, but what i don't know is that how can i find them in the linear layout and then setChecked(true); to each of the checkboxes

Comment: So, your statement that your "added programmatically" is misleading, because as far as I see, you create them in your XML, and then bind to them in code. Am I right?

Comment: no i really add the checkboxes in code, only the selectAll checkbox is in the xml, i showed the structure here so that you know what other views are in the layout